# How to I get the window handle by giving the process name that is running?

Tags: c#, process

How can I get the window handle by giving the process name or window title in c#.. given the process is in running already

Comment: See this to get child windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111/net-c-getting-child-windows-when-you-only-have-a-process-handle-or-pid/79205#79205

Comment: You assume a process has only one window.  Not a valid assumption.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the `Process` class.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("someName");

foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;

    // do something with windowHandle
}
```

Comment: +1.  Good answer.  This will work if it's the main window handle that's needed.

Comment: is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: I want to implement this in Java but didn't found way. Can you tell how can we achieve this is java?

Comment: Will not work if p.MainWindowHandle = hidden.