# C#/WPF image overlay on browsers

Tags: c#

I am working on a wpf project and want to open browser (IE,Chrome,Firefox,Microsoft edge) on button click. After the browser opens I need to detect it's settings button on right corner and display an arrow image or a tooltip pointing to it. 
I know how to open the browser using process.start but how to detect the settings area?

Comment: I think its not possible for the program itself. Moreover, the window size might be variable... you have to take these into account as well.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this. I believe that you are going down the wrong direction. What are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: It is a very complicated and possibly wrong approach. AFAIK no browser have such API. It would be much easier and convenient to show a screenshot of target browser with the arrow drawn on. For your approach, you may measure the exact location of settings menu as percentages on your PC, and then after you launch browser, you set the focus to your app by handles, and then show a new transparent window as overlay on top with arrows drawn to your new window based on measured percentages and target window size.

Answer (score 0):

Get the browser's handle (HWND) after you open it (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953582/how-to-i-get-the-window-handle-by-giving-the-process-name-that-is-running)), and read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815667/how-to-draw-graphics-text-on-top-of-another-application) on how to draw the arrow.

What you're trying to do is not easy, and has many points of possible failure, so I would avoid it, if some alternative was present.