# Is it possible to get a window of another application from another one?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have two projects (TestVisual and RecordPlayBack). TestVisual has two windows (MainWindow and TestWindow). I can get the TestWindow instance by using below code,

```
var windows = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows;
IntPtr twHandle = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(windows[2]).Handle;
```

Now, i run the RecordPlayBack.exe from TestVisual.wpf application. So, the Application.Current holds RecordPlayBack application where the TestWindow is not available. In this case, how to get the TestWindow instance of TestVisual application?

i have tried this below code,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

IntPtr twHandle =(IntPtr) User32.FindWindow("test", null);
```

Please suggest me any ideas.

Note:
RecordPlayBack project is added as referrence to TestVisual project.

Thanks,

Comment: This has possibly been asked before, take a look for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953582/how-to-i-get-the-window-handle-by-giving-the-process-name-that-is-running or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547639/return-window-handle-by-its-name-title. Hope these answers help!

Comment: Hi @GrahamMc, Thanks for your suggestions. I have added the screenshot of my application, please look that. I have tried the below suggestion, 

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

but it capture the "RecordWindow" because i'm trying to capture the "TestWindow" while clicking stop button in RecordWindow. So in this case, RecordWindow comes front. 

Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: maybe take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281429/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-within-a-process for how to get a list of all windows in a process. Once you get the process using your answer, you can then list all the windows and find the correct window?

Answer (score 1):

I can get the window handle in another application by using below code,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(System.Diagnostics.Process p in processes)
{
    if(p.MainWindowTitle == "Test Window")
    {
        twHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
        break;
    }
}
```