# Get Child window using ProcessID or Window Handle?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

My program A launched program B (both are separate exe's). Now my program B need to find if A have any modal/child window open using A's processID.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the soln. 
1. Get handle of parent window A.
PerformanceCounter perId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
2. Use GetLastActivePopup method to get last active popup (Last popup works in my case :) ) .

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use some of the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111/net-c-getting-child-windows-when-you-only-have-a-process-handle-or-pid) (if you don't mind using Win32 calls).

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have been trying same thing ;) will update if I succeed

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Good luck.