# How to control an application's control(?) in c#?

Tags: c#, controls, handle

I am trying to make an application that puts a url into an opened chrome's address bar. I am making it for myself because chrome does not allow me to enter a new url in full screen mode.

So...in c#, I can  get handle of chrome. The problem is...I have no idea how to put url into chrome's address bar in c# code.

is it even possible?

I am not looking for a working source code. Any idea would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not set on C#, try looking into [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)... you should be able to find some way of entering text into the right place and pressing enter... that's at least where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

When i was young, i used delphi's tool called "Process Viewer" or something like that. It could show main controls in opened windows. Knowing control's name you can get its handle. Having its handle you can do everything =) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111/net-c-getting-child-windows-when-you-only-have-a-process-handle-or-pid) is a bit more info =)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be possible. Start a new process and set the -url argument to the address you wish to open. You can validate this from a command prompt or start menu, so I don't see any reason it wouldn't work in code, assuming the assembly has the appropriate level of trust.

```
chrome.exe -url www.mysite.com
```

Chrome apparently can be started with a variety of command line arguments, although I didn't see the `-url` switch on the list.

http://www.waltercedric.com/component/content/article/261-google/1713-google-chrome-exhaustive-command-line-switches.html

Quick article on spawning new processes w/ arguments in c#: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx

MSDN documentation and samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx